# "In modo di" versus "in modo da"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, difference, phrase-choice

Cercando su Internet ho trovato esempi di uso di tutte e due queste locuzioni, ma non riesco a capire quali siano le differenze tra l'una e l'altra. Per fare un esempio, quale sarebbe la forma corretta, "in modo di" oppure "in modo da", in una frase come questa?

> - Penso che, in tali circostanze, sia meglio lasciar passare un po' di tempo *in modo di* essere più sereni e poter esprimersi meglio.
> - Penso che, in tali circostanze, sia meglio lasciar passare un po' di tempo *in modo da* essere più sereni e poter esprimersi meglio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tra le due frasi indicate, quella giusta è esclusivamente la seconda. Infatti, in italiano esiste la locuzione congiuntiva *in modo da* che introduce una proposizione subordinata all'infinito. Se il soggetto della subordinata è lo stesso della sua principale, si può quindi usare *in modo da* + infinito.

Esiste anche una locuzione simile che può essere usata come congiunzione consecutiva, *in modo che*, la quale regge una proposizione subordinata in un modo finito e permette di avere una subordinata con un soggetto diverso. Non esiste invece *in modo di* come congiunzione.

Tuttavia, si può trovare *fare in modo di*. Questa frase usa sia *di* che *da* in una maniera che può aiutare a mettere in luce la differenza:

> Fa' in modo di arrivare in tempo, in modo da non trovare una coda troppo lunga alle casse del cinema.

Si noti la virgola, che ci dà un'indicazione interessante, perché sarebbe assurdo mettere la virgola tra *fa'* e *in modo di*. Infatti, nel primo caso, *fare in modo* è un'espressione indivisibile, è come se fosse un verbo a sé stante. L'espressione *fare in modo* funziona come qualsiasi altro verbo che introduca una subordinata e regge *di* + infinito oppure *che* + finito. Ecco quindi come dobbiamo pensare (e pronunciare!) la frase:

> Fa'-in-modo di arrivare in tempo, in-modo-da non trovare una coda troppo lunga alle casse del cinema.

Questo spiega la regola che sembra arbitraria (e che si trova per esempio mal espressa [qui](http://faustoraso.blogspot.it/2014/02/in-modo-di-o-in-modo-da.html)) che può essere riassunta in questo modo: si usa sempre *in modo da* tranne quando si dice *fare in modo di*.

A proposito di *fare in modo da*: a me sembra semplicemente sbagliato. Si è portato nei commenti sotto un'altra domanda l'esempio di una pagina di Treccani che cita *farò in modo da contentarti*; l'esempio sembra obsoleto e sospetto che l'equivoco nasca dalla quasi omofonia con *farò in modo d'accontentarti* (già dicendo *farò in modo da soddisfarti* l'esempio suona molto peggio). Se tuttavia si trattasse di un frammento di una frase anche solo leggermente più lunga, dove fosse possibile immaginare una virgola dopo *farò*, per quanto spiegato sopra sarebbe accettabile. Per esempio:

> Lo farò, in modo da accontentarti.

Comment: Sul concetto di “sbagliato” e sulla diffusione di “fare in modo da”, vedi i miei commenti sotto la mia risposta.

Comment: Interessante risposta. Tuttavia, resta da chiarire se "fare in modo da" possa considerarsi sbagliato oppure un'espressione in disuso.

Comment: @Charo Credo che sia in disuso, dunque, in un certo senso, sbagliata. Anche le occorrenze recenti nei libri che trovi su Google Books sono o citazioni di roba vecchia o testi scritti in uno stile... ehm... particolare. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Il dizionario Treccani, alla [voce “modo”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/modo/) (vedi punto 6.c), contempla solo la forma “in modo da” (oltre ovviamente ad altre costruzioni di significato analogo, ma che si costruiscono diversamente, come “in modo che” e “di modo che”).

Comment: Curiosamente però in [questa pagina della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/evitare/) si trova questo esempio di uso di "in modo di": 《Evitare una persona, fare *in modo di* non incontrarla, anche abitualmente, per non avere contatti con lei.》

Comment: Non me ne ero mai accorto! In effetti esiste l'espressione *fare in modo di* che è giusta così (*fare in modo da* sarebbe sbagliato), ma se vuoi usarlo fuori da quella espressione devi usare *in modo da*. Che complicazione...

Comment: @MauroVanetti Perché “fare in modo da” dovrebbe essere sbagliato? A parte che a me non suona male (il che non vuol dire niente), il Treccani alla voce citata esemplifica “farò in m. da contentarti” e il solito [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fare+in+modo+da%2Cfare+in+modo+di&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfare%20in%20modo%20da%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfare%20in%20modo%20di%3B%2Cc0) mostra una minoritaria ma sostanziosa presenza di “fare in modo da” nei testi stampati.

Comment: Rompicapo interessante. Quello che volevo dire è che _fare in modo_ regge _di_ con l'infinito. _Farò in modo da contentarti_ a me sembra proprio sbagliato a meno che vogliamo scomporlo come _farò_ + _in modo da_ + _contentarti_... ma cosa farò? Si potrebbe semmai dire _Farò quanto desideri in modo da contentarti_ oppure _Farò il bravo in modo da contentarti_. (Ma poi... _contentarti_?! _accontentarti_ in italiano d'oggi.)

Comment: @Mauro: la tua osservazione mi sembra molto interessante. Potresti includerla in una risposta?

Comment: @Charo Ho sentito una persona "del ramo" che mi ha dato alcune dritte. Scrivo una risposta.

Comment: @MauroVanetti In attesa della risposta, spero anche che spiegherai anche perché “fare in modo da” sarebbe “sbagliato”: le fonti fanno ritenere che, al massimo, sia antiquato così come anche, forse, [“contentare”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contentare&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontentare%3B%2Cc0), che però sembra ancora vivo. Ti prego solo di non bollare come “sbagliate” forme che magari sono solo lontane da noi come epoca o come diffusione all'interno del paese.

Comment: Be', OK, "sbagliato" naturalmente significa sempre solo quello se si parla di una lingua viva.

Comment: @MauroVanetti Veramente “sbagliato” è diverso da “antiquato” o da “usato prevalentemente in certe parti d'Italia”.

Comment: Sarebbe interessante approfondire questo concetto. Secondo me è un uso "sbagliato" della lingua quello che fa recepire un messaggio in un modo diverso da quello che desiderava il mittente del messaggio. Ogni "errore" può essere fatto di proposito per uno scopo particolare. Se uno dicesse che fa in modo da contentarmi perché vuole sembrare il marchese Carabuzzolis o il villano Bertoldo, va benissimo e mi considererò molto contentato. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sicuramente 'in modo da' è la forma corretta lì.