# Perché "farne" non è corretto (in un contesto particolare)?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, pronouns, particles

Quando ho scritto [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3695/707), ho messo la frase "per farne un esempio", ma poi mi è stata corretta in "per fare un esempio". Avevo pensato che si dovesse usare la particella pronominale "ne" per indicare "per fare un esempio di quello che ho scritto prima". Questo tipo di costruzione con la particella "ne" è molto usuale nella mia lingua, il catalano, e credevo che fosse lo stesso in italiano. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: perché non è corretto mettere la particella "ne" in tale contesto?

Comment: Secondo me sarebbe andato benissimo anche “farne”. Direi che in quella frase è corretto ma solo meno idiomatico di “fare”.

Comment: E tu, @DaG, l'avresti scritto 'farne' lì?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"*Farne*" si usa in riferimento a qualcosa di cui hai già parlato in precedenza, come appunto hai scritto in riferimento alla particella **ne**. Stai quindi sottintendendo il complemento oggetto della frase.

Sapendo questo, scrivere "*Farne un esempio*" non è concettualmente sbagliato, in quanto stai specificando che "fai un esempio di qualcosa".
Diciamo che è uso comune dire "*Fare un esempio*", dando per scontato che è riferito a quello di cui si sta già parlando.

*Farne* invece si usa piuttosto in frasi come "*Non riesco a **farne** a meno*" o "*Vorrei **farne** parte*".

Answer (score 2):

È corretto anche "farne",

Il "ne" in italiano ha la stessa funzione grammaticale che ha in catalano (entrambe le lingue infatti mettono in difficoltà i parlanti del castigliano, che non ha queste particelle, quando le studiano).
Però l'uso corrente può a volte essere diverso (nel senso che un certo uso può essere idiomatico in una lingua e un po' meno nell'altra, e viceversa).

(btw, vale anche per il "ci"/"hi".)